# How do I Include \news.php?

Tags: php, include, newline

I am trying to include a php document which name is news.php, but because I am doing this on a local server files navigate trough  \ and not /

My code looks as follows:

```
<?php include("\xnews\news.php");?>
```

But because of the \n which in php means newline (I believe) the output views the error:

```
Warning: include(\xnews\ews.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\Users\Johanne-PC\Desktop\EasyPHP-12.0\www\my portable files\Homepage\news.php on line 44
```

**Is there any way I can bypass this and include it successfully?**

Comment: Escape your ` \ ` by using ` \\ `.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use \:

```
<?php include("\\xnews\\news.php");
```

You can also use single quotes (which don't escape):

```
<?php include('\xnews\news.php');
```

Additionally, you can (edit: on all systems), use /:

```
<?php include('/xnews/news.php');
```

Comment: Using forward slashes has nothing to do with Apache. Support is built into Windows (actually since MS-DOS 2.0 where directories where bolted on). So you should preferrably use them for *all* paths; less compatibility woes once you use a normal server.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `\` is what's known as the escape character - it's used in special circumstances, such as `\n` being a newline. So to get an actual `\` character, you have to escape it with a second `\`. As the other answers have said, you need to use:

```
<?php include("\\xnews\\news.php");?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php include("\\xnews\\news.php");?>
```